# Scala implicit parameter

Tags: scala, monads, typeclass

Okay, I finally managed to understand the use case of implicit in function parameters and got my type classes working. Let's have a look at my monad type class:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] extends Functor[M] { self =>
  def pure[a](value: a): M[a]

  def flatMap[a, b](ma: M[a])(f: a => M[b]): M[b]
}
```

I created a type class instance for my parser monad (which is just a dummy for now):

```
case class Parser[a](value: (Unit => a)) {
  def >>=[b](f: a => Parser[b])(implicit p: Monad[Parser]): Parser[b] =
    p.flatMap(this)(f)

  def fmap[b](f: a => Parser[b])(implicit p: Monad[Parser]): Parser[b] =
    p.map(this)(f)
}

object Parser {
  implicit object MonadInstance extends Monad[Parser] {
    override def pure[a](value: a): Parser[a] =
      new Parser[a]({ _ => value })

    override def flatMap[a, b](ma: Parser[a])(f: (a) => Parser[b]): Parser[b] =
      f(ma.value())

    override def map[a, b](fa: Parser[a])(f: (a) => b): Parser[b] =
      new Parser[b]({ _ => f(fa.value()) })
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering, if I can use the monad instance without having to declare an implicit parameter wherever I use my monads. Is there some way to "import" the functionality globally?

Comment: If you have the specific type you can summon the implicit wherever you need it, `implicitly[Monad[Parser]]`. But you can't and shouldn't be able to add functions to an object completely invisibly - that would be a recipe for impossibly unreadable code and nightmarish debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in Predef called implicitly that is designed for this use case:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit t: T):T = t
```

which can be used like this:

```
val mParser = implicitly[Monad[Parser]]
```

Original:

In scala, implicits are automatically looked for in the companion objects of the relevant types. So implicitly[Monad[Parser]] ought to just work, because it ought to look in object Parser.

Note that because of the way the interpreter works, it's a bit of a pain to define companion objects in the repl. The easiest thing is to wrap them in an object, or to not start object Parser on a new line (just for the repl).

Comment: What I really wanted to know is, if there is some other way to automagically get the type class instance for the parser monad. But anyway, the note about the REPL is nice to know.

Comment: If you use :paste the repl will compile the code as one block so you can define the companion object together.

Comment: @bash0r ah, do you mean maybe implicitly[Monad[Parser]] ?

Comment: @dlwh Ya, exactly. That was what I was looking for! Can you change your answer so I can accept it?